# Meta tag not working to change address bar color's of safari desktop in dark mode

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries, meta-tags

I want to change the color of my site's top bar address on Safari desktop. I firstly try to use CSS, but I quickly find the HTML meta tag "theme-color" with the media query "(prefers-color-scheme: light or black)" solution.

Here are the two lines of code I use:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#dc891c" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)"/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#dc891c" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"/>
```

This solution is working perfectly great except for that color code (#dc891c the one I want :/) in dark mode.

It worked with all the others hex code I tried in both light and dark mode but my color won't display in dark mode.

I'm working with the Next framework using typescript, react and tailwind.

Comment: Where is dark mode enabled? Not sure how it works in Safari, but if you have set dark mode in Google Chrome but your system settings is in light mode, it will prioritize your system settings.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti, thx for your comment. Dark is enabled in my system directly depending on time. But, as I said, it works for every color I tried except mine.